# How to get jQuery variable value in PHP file

Tags: php, jquery

I need to jQuery variable value in PHP code in same file with out calling ajax? Please help me it is possible or not. Here jQuery and PHP code here given below.

Comment: You will need to use ajax for this. You can't escape from it.

Comment: jQuery is font end, handled by the browser. PHP is backend handled by the server which is executed BEFORE the browser displays the content.

Answer (score 5):

well you can make use of `jquery.session` plugin to store Session variable and then you can access that variable using php code.

**Sample Code**

```
$(function() {
      $.session("myVar", "value");
});
```

**In PHP**

```
echo $_SESSION['myVar'];
```