# use of jquery.session in php

Tags: php, jquery, session

I use [JQuery-Session-Plugin](https://github.com/AlexChittock/JQuery-Session-Plugin) to store session in jquery and use this session in php.
Problem is session value is get in jquery but not in php.

`JQuery:`

```
var selected = $.map($('.selectbox option:selected'),function(e) { return $(e).val(); } );
$.session.set('did_ext', selected);
alert($.session.get('did_ext'));
```

now i want this value in php.
I use `<?php echo $_SESSION['did_ext'];?>`

but this is not working. I refer [this quetion's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18401110/how-to-get-jquery-variable-value-in-php-file) and apply it in my code.

Actually i use jquery-steps, in 1 step i have a multiple selectbox and in 2 step i have need of this selectbox  value. I use this values in php.

So what is the problem here?
Is it possible with this method?
Any alternatives are also welcome.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sessions are server side, how can you generate a server side session on client side, rather use cookies which are accessed by both

Comment: I didn't see anything that links `JQuery-Session-Plugin` to the server side in their code.

Comment: as i said in quetion,i refer someone's answer and try this. so is it possible?

Comment: I don't think it is possible that way. PHP session are to be generated at server side not on client side.

Comment: ya true, i think i changed it with cookies.

Comment: you generate the session in the `step1` at server side (when the page first loads/authenticates) and when you request the second step the session will be available at the server . no need for another jQuery plugin.

Comment: don't rely much on cookies, they are easily manipulatable as it is client side.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if PHP and Jquery uses same session or not, but alternatively you can try forwarding jquery session using Get/Post to PHP--

At html side

```
window.location.href= "SessionForward.php?did_ext="+$.session.get('did_ext');
```

At PHP Side

```
<?php echo $_GET['did_ext'];?>
```

Comment: no,i use jquery-steps and i have a need of 1-step's value in 2nd step.